# Show that every Dedekind complete ordered field $K$ satisfies the Archimedean Axiom

Tags: number-theory

Given a contradiction first, every non-empty subset $A$ of $K$ has a least upper bound and for every $x,y \in F$, $nx < y$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So consider a set $\{a, 2a, 3a...\}$ and $b$ as the upper bound, then $b-a$ is an upper bound of $\{0, a, 2a...\}$ and so on, then somehow there exists no least upper bound? What about taking $b - na$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Suppose that $K$ is non-Archimedean; then there is an $x\in K$ such that $x>n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\Bbb N$ is bounded above in $K$. Since $K$ is Dedekind complete, $\Bbb N$ has a least upper bound $b$: $n\le b$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, but if $y<b$, there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n>y$. Now consider $b-1$ to get a contradiction.